# Optimal Cost Calculation for String Construction with Append and Clone Operations in C++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

**Problem Overview:**

I'm working on a string construction challenge where I aim to build a target string from scratch. The process involves two primary operations:

1. **Appending** any character to the current string. This operation has a fixed cost, denoted as (x).
2. **Cloning** a specific substring from the current string and appending it to the end. This operation comes with its own fixed cost, represented as (y).

The primary goal is to determine the most cost-efficient method to construct the entire target string, taking into account the costs of both operations.

For a given string, both the append cost ((x)) and the clone cost ((y)) will be provided. The challenge is to compute the minimum possible cost required to construct the string using a combination of the two operations.

I started by implementing a dynamic programming approach to tackle the problem. My strategy was to iterate over the string and decide at each position whether it's more cost-effective to append a character or clone a substring.

**What I tried:**
For each position in the string, I calculated the cost of appending the next character. I then checked if there's a previous substring that could be cloned to match a part of the target string. If the cloning operation was more cost-effective than appending, I opted to clone. I maintained a table to keep track of the minimum cost required to construct the string up to each position.

**Expectations:**
I expected my solution to correctly calculate the minimum cost for constructing various target strings, given the constraints and costs for appending and cloning.

**Actual Results:**
However, for some input strings, the computed cost was different from the expected result. Specifically, certain strings, when broken down step-by-step manually, yielded a different optimal cost than what my solution was generating.

For instance, for the string "abababab" with append cost 10 and clone cost 1, my initial logic computed the cost as 22, while the manual breakdown suggested the cost should be 21.

Comment: How can "abababab" be built with cost 21 in that example?

Comment: Let's break down the construction of the string "abababab" with an append cost of 10 and a clone cost of 1:
**Target String:** "abababab"  
**Append Cost:** 10  
**Clone Cost:** 1  

**Steps:**

1. **Append 'a'**  
   Cost: 10  
   Current String: "a"

2. **Append 'b'**  
   Cost: 10  
   Current String: "ab"

3. **Clone 'ab'**  
   Cost: 1  
   Current String: "abab"

4. **Clone 'ab'**  
   Cost: 1  
   Current String: "abababab"

**Total Cost:** 10 + 10 + 1 + 1 = 22
I was wrong about the cost being 21, but I am not sure

Comment: I know some computations that are correct

Comment: Example 1:  Target "aa" that has append cost 1, clone cost 2: the cheapest cost is 2:

- Start with an empty string, "'"

- Append 'a' (cost 1), giving the string "a"

- Append 'a' (cost 1), giving the string "aa"

Comment: Example 2: - Target "aaaa" that has append cost 2, clone cost 3: the cheapest cost is 7:

- Start with an empty string, "'"

- Append 'a' (cost 2), giving the string "a"

- Append 'a' (cost 2), giving the string "aa"

- Clone "aa" (cost 3 ), giving the string "aaaa"

Comment: Example 3: - Target "xzxpzxzxpq", append cost 10, clone cost 11: the cheapest cost is 71 :

- Start with an empty string, "'"

- Append ' $x$ ' (cost 10): " $x$ "

- Append ' $z$ ' (cost 10): "xz"

- Append ' $x$ ' (cost 10): "xzx"

- Append 'p' (cost 10): "xzxp"

- Append ' $z$ ' (cost 10): "xzxpz"

- Clone "xzxp" (cost 11): "xzxpzxzxp"

- Append 'q' (cost 10) : "xzxpzxzxpq"

Comment: Could be worth thinking about the problem from the solution back towards the empty string. Smaller search space than going forwards.

Comment: While more efficient than some naive methods, this approach may still have some performance concerns for very long strings. Our solution should work for strings of 30,000 characters in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: But you want to calculate the minimum cost, not actually build the string. A trie comes to mind...

Comment: I do have a dynamic programming solution, but it's really inefficient, and whenever I try to optimize it, the test cases fail

Comment: This code uses dynamic programming to minimize the cost of constructing a target string. It considers two operations: appending a character and cloning a substring. The `dp` array stores the minimum cost for each string length, starting from an empty string.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the problem as well?

Comment: please add all required details to your question